# moving a point along a circular path via mouse motion (python/pygame)

Tags: python, rotation, pygame, geometry

The problem: move a point along a circular path with mouse input as a guide.

There are plenty of solutions online for moving a point along a circular path, namely using the center + math.sin||cos(angle) * radius equation and incrementing the angle. This doesn't work with mouse input, however; even at a fraction of the original x/y value and converted to radians your "circle" has no constant radius and the path point moves in a strange relationship to the mouse's position.

My inkling is that the path point (point on the circumference of the circle) needs to be restricted to a certain distance from the origin (an enforced radius). I also get the feeling that either y needs to be a function of x or x needs to be a function of y.

I've gone down the road of using the distance formula to check the distance from the path point to the center of the circle. The idea was to then "snap" the x and y values back by the allowed distance - true distance but that...didn't work. Namely because there's a difference between the distance between two points and the difference between two points (how I'm *beginning* to understand it is that the difference between two points yields a vector?). At any rate, I'm sure there's a more straightforward solution.

[image: rotating arm guided by a mouse]
(let's...pretend the rotating arm is centered, for the sake of the illustration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for trigonometric functions.
You were on a good path by calculating the distance to the center.
Imagine a vector from circle center to mouse position.
The point now has to lie somewhere in the same direction
as this vector, which means we can calculate its position
with a simple [scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication). The only thing that remains is
to calculate the scalar, which is the proportion
between mouse distance and circle radius:

```
from __future__ import division # For Python 2.7
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

CENTER = (200, 200)
RADIUS = 100

satelliteCenter = (CENTER[0]+RADIUS, CENTER[1])

running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT: running = False

  mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  vector = (mouse[0]-CENTER[0], mouse[1]-CENTER[1])
  distance = (vector[0]**2 + vector[1]**2)**0.5

  if distance > 0:
    scalar = RADIUS / distance
    satelliteCenter = (
      int(round( CENTER[0] + vector[0]*scalar )),
      int(round( CENTER[1] + vector[1]*scalar )) )

  screen.fill((152,206,231))
  pygame.draw.circle(screen, (71,153,192), CENTER, RADIUS)
  pygame.draw.circle(screen, (243,79,79), satelliteCenter, 16)
  pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark! The trigonometric function raised a Zero Division Error. It could probably be worked around this by making a barrier around the center of the circle where all values got for mousex and mousey are set to 1. I also encountered sensitivity--when I moved my mouse the endpoint would go flitting about the circle. I wonder if there's not a way to involve angular velocity in the equation to remedy this. 

@Meyer, this is wonderful! What are the elements inside of the vector tuple called? (if there is a name.)

Comment: Also, not on the topic directly but I notice that CENTER[0] + vector[0]*scalar has the same form as center + cos(theta) * radius. Curious.

Comment: I know the elements as vector coordinates, or vector components.
As for the division by zero, I embarrassingly forgot about that as well,
and fixed the code accordingly. Note that `satelliteCenter` is now only updated when the distance is not zero. Yes, there is a close relationship to the cosine of the angle between vectors,
see for example the Wikipedia entry on [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the x, y origin of the circle, and the x, y position of the mouse to calculate the angle between the mouse and the circle using: `tan((y_mouse-y_circle)/(x_mouse-x_circle))` then the position of the point would be `(x_circle + r * cos(angle), y_circle + r * sin(angle))`